# Check DKIM Signature From Domain

Tags: node.js, express, dns

Is there a way to check the DKIM Signature via Node JS?

I've tried something like this

```
dns.resolveTxt('acme.com', (err, addresses) => console.log(addresses));
```

But it's only providing the SPF record. Perhaps there is a subdomain I need to check under the domain for the DKIM Signature?

My end goal is to just determine if the domain has a DKIM set up or not. Thank you!

Comment: The DKIM pseudo record is somewhere under `_domainkey` but you will need to know the selector to use (visible in the emails). It is not under apex of domain. Also please use `example.com` when obfuscating names. Plus at this stage your question is not so much related to programming. "My end goal is to just determine if the domain has a DKIM set up or not." You can't except if you know the selector. Or you look at the DMARC record which is at a fixed known place in advance, and do some heuristics based on that.

Comment: Also about `resolveTxt`: there could be a lot of other TXT records completely unrelated to SPF/DKIM/DMARC. You have to parse them, find a `v=something` at start. Just doing a DNS query is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a webserver. I can send emails to xxx@domain.com
therefore i created a dkim like this on the dns : mail._domainkey.domain.com.

i can, for exemple, use dig to get txt data stored on the dns. It goes like this :

```
$> dig mail._domainkey.domain.com. txt
...
mail._domainkey.domain.com. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAO...yUgBBeewIDAQAB"
...
```

but you would need to know the selector of the dkim. (for me its "mail" but it can be anything) the email sender chooses which one it uses, and write it in the email headers.

in nodejs this works for my domain :

```
require('dns').resolveTxt('mail._domainkey.domain.com.', console.log);
```

see more here :
https://serverfault.com/questions/625008/find-dkim-and-dmarc-records/832546

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a domain has DKIM set up by searching the domain name on [registry.prove.email](https://registry.prove.email), which has indexed 5,000+ common websites and their DKIM keys + selectors.